# Sniffing packet between Android Apps

Tags: android

I'm trying to make an application that sniff packet to research what packets are sending 
and receiving between Android apps on my phone. 
(It doesn't need another phone. Just be operated on my phone for test)
When a specific Android Application sends packets to an another Android application,
my app(I want to make) will catch those packets.
This is what I want to make.

But during technical research, I found out sniffing data needs root privilege.
And I'm not sure if a third party app can take data between another Apps.

So my questions are:

A) There are 3 apps. A,B,C. Is there any possibility C app can take or sniff packet
   between A and B without root privilege? if it can't, then how about with root privilege?

B) Communication between Apps needs to use Intent. So I thought if I can take that Intent between other Apps, maybe I solve this problem. But I don't know how and if it can.

Is there any suggestion to solve this?

Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: As far as I know, no you can't do that. For A) You're correct that you need root permission to sniff packets (network data). For B), refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060161/intercepting-an-intent-from-an-external-application)

Comment: i dont think you will find a solution here for such app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Yes, provided A, B and C were defined by the same vendor, who would know the exact implementation of the data sharing mechanism.

B) See [Interacting With Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html).

Comment: I think I didn't explain exactly. A,B would be made by the same vendor or not. They are just some application, they can be dropbox app, web browser or e-mail app, etc. And C is my app. I just want to know if C can do this.